# WPF InvalidArgument with MSDN CroppedImage example, "Value not in accepted range"

Tags: wpf, bitmap, resize-crop

I'm experiencing problems, namely InvalidArgument and "Value does not fall within accepted range" errors when creating a CroppedBitmap image. I cannot for the life of me find out why.

The button click =

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        BitmapSource i = (BitmapSource)FindResource("test");
        try
        {
            CroppedBitmap c = new CroppedBitmap(i, new Int32Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The resource dictionary references the bitmap :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<!-- Elbows -->
<BitmapImage x:Key="test" UriSource="./Assets/test.png" />
```

and included the App.xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="rdHMIControls.xaml" />
```

The BitmapSource (i) is valid and the call to CroppedBitmap throws the ArgumentException, "Value does not fall within the accepted range".

I've even taken another example straight off MSDN and the exact same problem happens

```
       BitmapSource i = (BitmapSource)this.FindResource("test");
        try
        {

            // Create an Image element.
            Image croppedImage = new Image();
            croppedImage.Width = 200;
            croppedImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);


            // Create a CroppedBitmap based off of a xaml defined resource.
            CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(
               i,
               new Int32Rect(30, 20, 105, 50));       //select region rect
            croppedImage.Source = cb;                 //set image source to cropped
```

Again new CroppedBitmap throws InvalidArgument exception

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: What is the size of `test.png`? If it's less than 100x100 pixels, that would explain the exception.

Comment: Doh! That's it Thanks. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Or delete the question?

Comment: Do you not want the credit?

Comment: I'd prefer the question to be deleted. It won't be of much help to others.

Comment: Yes it will help, I had the same error.

Comment: Same issue here too.